# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0. on Azure

Tags: azure, crystal-reports, azure-web-app-service

I use VS 2012 ,in my Azure portal I create new web App then I download publish profile file,but after publishing my site i get this error related to crystal report version

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` is typically present in the GAC on your location machine and that's why your local project might work. When publishing the project to Azure App Service, make sure that you **bin-deploy this DLL and any other dependent DLLs** so that your application can load them in Azure.